# How can I use a canvas framework within Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, canvas, polymer

I'm using polymer to create my own reusable HTML element. I want to be able to use a JavaScript canvas framework (ideally fabric.js) inside the Shadow DOM, but because the elements in the Shadow DOM aren't real elements, all the frameworks I have tried don't really know what to do with them.

By way of an example, I have a Polymer element has the template of

```
 <template>

   <div id="canvas" width="200" height="50"></div>

 </template>
```

Were this normal HTML, I could then use `new fabric.Canvas('canvas')` to create a fabric-enabled canvas. However I tried this in the "ready" function, but it fails (saying something like that the position property doesn't exist). I also tried with KineticJS with a similar result.

Comment: Elements in shadow dom are real elements, can you clarify? Canvas can absolutely be used within Shadow DOM. I suspect what's happening is that the libs you're using don't understand Shadow DOM, so they're trying to look for containers that are within the shadow tree. Can you post an example of what you're trying?

Comment: Well I figured they must be somewhat unusual elements because they can have non-unique element ids. I'll edit my original with an example. Thanks!

Comment: Gausie is talking about how elements in shadow trees aren't in the same `id` namespace as elements in the document tree. fabric.js at some point probably calls `document.getElementById('canvas')`, thus not looking in shadow trees.

Comment: Yeah so is there a library that does work with shadow trees?

Comment: I tried passing a canvas element into a fabric element as content in the light dom. That made the errors go away but nothing rendered to the screen. Oddly enough the dev tools reported dimensions of the canvas but mousing over the element in element's panel didn't indicate it was positioned anywhere on screen.

Comment: I've actually just got to the same point (except I used fabricCanvas.wrapperEl). Need to work out these position issues now...

Comment: Since I only need StaticCanvas, I'm not going to worry about the non-existent position!

Comment: I've this problem as says by @robdodson "canvas but mousing over the element in element's panel didn't indicate". In fabric.js found one appendChild and another replaceChild but this actions wasn't add wrapperEL (created by fabric) correctly in my custom element. Thus, I'm adding it in the my **ready** lifecycle function so:

`
this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas(referenceId);
...
this.canvas.wrapperEl.insertBefore(self.$.canvas, this.canvas.wrapperEl.childNodes[1]);
this.appendChild(self.canvas.wrapperEl);
...

`
where **this.canvas** is object (instance) returned by fabric.